# How do I remove "trash" option that appears on the sidebar of the file explorer in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: unity, 16.04, filemanager

I have come across many solutions to editing and configuring "places" section on the sidebar of the file explorer in unity but the file in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file does not have any option to remove the "Trash" option. Could someone help me regarding this?